# How to simplify the following?

Tags: functions, logarithms

Good day,

I am trying to show that $P_1 = P_2$ given the following:

$q \times ln[w-R+G] + (1-q)\times ln[w-R+B] = ln(w-P_1) $

$q\times ln[w+G] + (1-q)\times ln[w+B] = ln(w-P_2)$

where $q \in [0,1]$.

$w, R, G$ and $w$ are fixed quantities.

Intuitively, the two prices should be equal because of the constant risk aversion coefficient of the log function. However, I am unsure on how to obtain such result algebraically.

Thanks.

Comment: Which of the other variables are parameters of the problem and not allowed to vary and which are allowed to vary over a range to create equations you can use?  I am guessing you have the equations for all $x,y$ in some range and $P_1,P_2$ are functions of $x,y$.

Comment: Edited. For simplicity, I can assume that $x, y$ are both equal to $w$. Apologies, must've been a typo.

Comment: But $R,G,B$ are supplied and fixed and the equations are true for all $q$ in the range?  What about $w$?

Comment: Edited. They are all fixed and exogenously determined.